# SQLite transactions in a multi-threaded application

Tags: c#, multithreading, sqlite, transactions

I have done some searching and I know that in order to have one SQLite database file be updated from different threads in the same application, the threads have to share the same `SQLiteConnection` object.  I've taken steps in my application to make that happen.

My question has to do with transactions.  I need each thread to perform its updates in one transaction, and I need each transaction to be totally isolated from the others.  That is, rolling back or committing a transaction in thread A should have no effect on the work being done by thread B.

Do I have to do anything special to make this happen, or is creating one `SQLiteTransaction` at the start of the operation in each thread and assigning it to the `SQLiteCommand's Transaction` property enough?

Comment: if your threads are sharing a connection, then they'll be sharing transactions, server-side variables, default dbs, etc... the server won't have any clue that there's multiple "users" on the other end. you'd have to establish a separate connection in each thread to keep things separate.

Comment: I get "Database is locked" errors when I do that.  I'm trying to avoid these errors and keep the transactions separate.  And I can't fold the separate threads into one thread. Looks like I'll have to serialize the transactions on my own.

Comment: I've been fighting long time with this problem. I ended up using a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` to allow only one writer at a time.

Comment: You need one connection per thread, but SQLite does not allow much parallelism. Please read the [FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After playing around with this, I have figured out that my earlier conclusion regarding needing to share a single connection across threads was wrong.  Each thread now:

1. Uses a special singleton class called `ConnectionManager` that creates `SQLiteConnection` instances, opens them, and configures common settings that have to be set after each connection is opened.
2. Creates a new connection before it accesses the database by calling a method in the `ConnectionManager` class.
3. Starts and manages any transactions in the usual way.
4. Closes and disposes of the `SQLiteConnection` in the usual way.

The `ConnectionManager` class allows all code that needs to connect to the database to obtain their connection, with all of the database settings set in a consistent manner.  Most of the properties my code needs to set are actually in the connection string, but there is one that can't be specified there, so I needed another mechanism.  Here's what the `ConnectionManager` looks like:

```
public class ConnectionManager {

    public int BusyTimeout { get; set; }

    public static ConnectionManager Instance {
        get {
            if ( iInstance == null ) {
                lock ( instanceLock ) {
                    if ( iInstance == null )
                        iInstance = new ConnectionManager();
                }
            }
            return iInstance;
        }
    }
    private static ConnectionManager iInstance = null;

    private static object instanceLock;

    private ConnectionManager() {
        BusyTimeout = Convert.ToInt32( TimeSpan.FromMinutes( 2 ).TotalMilliseconds );
    }

    static ConnectionManager() {
        instanceLock = new object();
    }

    public SQLiteConnection CreateConnection( string connectionString ) {
        SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection( connectionString );
        connection.Open();

        using ( SQLiteCommand command = connection.CreateCommand() ) {
           command.CommandText = string.Format( "PRAGMA busy_timeout={0}", BusyTimeout );
           command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

To use the `ConnectionManager` class, either an instance variable or a local variable is set to a copy of the singleton instance like this:

```
_connectionManager = ConnectionManager.Instance;
```

To obtain and use a database connection, code like this is used in each thread:

```
using ( SQLiteConnection connetion = _connectionManager.CreateConnection( connectionString ) {
    // Thread's database operation code here
}
```

It turns out the real trick to making it work was to set the busy_timeout pragma to something longer than the default.  SQLite internally is fully thread-safe and serializes requests on its own, so your code just needs to tell SQLite to wait for any currently executing operation to finish.  Our code is already structured so that failures in the database engine for any reason cause the operation to be retried after waiting a few seconds, so this works well.

The default 2 minute wait time is long enough for 99.99% of all operations to finish.  Really, if something take longer than 2 minutes to complete, we need to revisit that area and make it faster any way.

Answer (score 0):

I may be mistaken but for multi threaded applications I think you have to only have one connection to the database at a time.  I can't see how your code prevents 2 threads from both trying to connect to the same database at the same time.  If 2 threads do try to get a connection at the same time you the last thread to try to get the connection will get a SQLITE_BUSY response when it tries to open the connection used by the other thread.  You want to lock on the creation of the connection as such:

```
public class ConnectionManager
{

    public static int BusyTimeout { get; set; }

    public static object instanceLock;

    static ConnectionManager()
    {
        instanceLock = new object();
        BusyTimeout = Convert.ToInt32(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2).TotalMilliseconds);
    }

    public static SQLiteConnection CreateConnection(string connectionString)
    {
        SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();

        using (SQLiteCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = string.Format("PRAGMA busy_timeout={0}", BusyTimeout);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

And here is an example of a data access object that uses the connection manager.

```
class UserDAO
{


    public void UpdateUser(User user)
    {
        int result = -1;
        string connectionString = "Data Source=C:\\Counter\\Counter.sqlite";
        lock (ConnectionManager.instanceLock)
        {
            using (SQLiteConnection conn = ConnectionManager.CreateConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE counter_user " +
                        "SET runnerfirstname=@runnerfirstname, " +
                        "runnerlastname=@runnerlastname, " +
                        "parentlastname=@parentlastname, " +
                        "parentfirstname=@parentfirstname, " +
                        "runnergrade=@runnergrade, " +
                        "email=@email, " +
                        "laps=@laps, " +
                        "vestnumber=@vestnumber, " +
                        "tagid=@tagid " +
                        "WHERE id=@id";

                    cmd.Prepare();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@runnerfirstname", user.RunnerFirstName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@runnerlastname", user.RunnerLastName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parentlastname", user.ParentLastName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parentfirstname", user.ParentFirstName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@runnergrade", user.RunnerGrade);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", user.Email);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@laps", user.Laps);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vestnumber", user.VestNumber);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tagid", user.TagId);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", user.Id);

                    try
                    {
                        result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (SQLiteException e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("test");
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've been out of that job for over 2 years now, so the details have been totally forgotten. As I remember, you can have as many threads as you want querying the database, but only one can be writing to it at a time. However, that's all I remember at this point.